# Storybook default selection control value

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I'm using Storybook with React, and trying to add storybook select control with default value, but with no success.
There's nothing about that in documentation.
[image]

[image]

**I need one of the options above to be selected by default.**

```
    argTypes: {
        iconSrc: {
            options: Object.keys(iconTypes),
            mapping: iconTypes,
            control: {
                sort: 'requiredFirst',
                type: 'select',
                labels: {
                    BlueStep: 'Blue Step',
                    Step: 'Step',
                    Globe: 'Globe',
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add the `table` key

your storybook will look like this:

```
 argTypes: {
        iconSrc: {
            options: Object.keys(iconTypes),
            mapping: iconTypes,
            control: {
                sort: 'requiredFirst',
                type: 'select',
                labels: {
                    BlueStep: 'Blue Step',
                    Step: 'Step',
                    Globe: 'Globe',
                },
            },
            table: {
              type: { summary: 'select' },
              defaultValue: { summary: 'Step' },
            },
        },
    }
```

Comment: This is the way.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need pass args to your story template like:

```
const Template = (args) => <YourComponent {...props} />;

export const Default = Template.bind({});

Default.args = {
  iconSrc: 'icon-source-string',
};
```

Example from storybook official doc: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/controls

Comment: What if we already define the default value in our React component? How do we get storybook to get those values?

Comment: If you want to use default values from React component, either don't pass that prop in args or pass value as undefined

Comment: If we pass nothing or undefined, the control will not show the selected default value

Answer (score 0):

The most upvoted answer at time of writing refers to the [`table`](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/api/arg-types#table) key, which is used for specifying how an `arg` is *documented*.

However the question is asking how to set a default that will be the initially selected option on the `<select/>` element rendered when using the `select` control. In the rendered HTML this would be done by setting the [`selected`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#selected) boolean on the `<option/>` intended as default.

It appears that Storybook does not expose a way to accomplish this, and that [this is by design](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/14579) (for better or worse). Instead an optional control value is initialized to `undefined`. [`defaultValue`](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/api/arg-types#defaultvalue) has been deprecated.